# How to calculate the distance between two points using x and y?

Tags: java

Create a game called FindAirport that creates two Airplane objects randomly located in a 1000 x 1000 mile square. 
One Airplane object represents an airport and never moves. 
The other represents a plane trying to find the airport. The user is allowed any number of flights, each time specifying the direction in degrees and
the distance traveled. 
At the end of each flight, the user is told the distance between the two objects. The game ends when the user comes within 5 miles of the airport. The object is to get within 5 miles of the airport in the least number of flights. Airplane class is complete, constructor is not.

```js
public class Airplane{
  private double x;
  private double y;
  public Airplane (double x, double y){
    x = this.x;
    y = this.y;
    }
  public void fly (double angle, double distance){
    x += Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * distance;
    y += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * distance;
    }
  public double getX(){
    return this.x;
    }
  public double getY(){
    return this.y;
  }
}
```

Comment: This formula has been well documented online many times. Use pythagoras' theorem.

Comment: use pythagorean `c^2 = a^2 + b^2`

Comment: Please don't just copy-paste your homework assignment verbatim into questions.

Comment: In future, try to do a bit more research before asking your question. It will save you time.

Comment: if you have two points in space for example p1(x1,y1) and p2(x2,y2) the distance is `distance = Math.sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 )`

Comment: @Ivan86 I don't think the xor operator is valid for doubles in Java... should use `Math.pow()` perhaps.

Comment: @GyroGearless you are right, I am not a java user so I just wrote it in a way everyone could understand.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [hypotenuse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot-double-double-).

```
public double distance(double x, double y) {
    return Math.hypot(x - this.x, y - this.y);
}
```

Square root of ((x - this.x)² + (y - this.y)²)

Comment: Can you write the constructor method?

Comment: This is some task. So experiment yourself - you have all classes. Do you want to store the destination airport in the class? Then you could add the airport to the constructor, and `public double distanceToDestination() { return distance(destinationAirpoirt.x, destinationAirport.y); }`